# shell scripting: moving files to another directory

Tags: linux, bash

I have a directory called directory1 to which we store some files daily.
I first try to remove the previous backup stored in directory2. Then I try to move the files in directory1 to directory2.
I run the following bash script with cron but seems to fail.
What is wrong with my code?

```
#!/bin/sh
/bin/rm -rf /directory2/*
/bin/mv /directory1/* /directory2/
```

And my /etc/crontab has the following line:

```
0 6 * * 6 root /root/scripts/files.move.sh
```

Comment: it looks like you are removing **directory1**... then trying to move the directory (which now doesn't exists) to directory2.

Comment: It fails in what sense? What happens when you run it directly (not through cron), does it work then?

Comment: sorry typo
I corrected the code here

Comment: fail means cronjob runs but the files are still in directory1 and not moved to directory2

Comment: does it work when you run it directly?

Comment: Should be more easier answer it if you could post the error message obtained running that command: for example, launching as root is failing as well? Could you post the entry in the cron file?

Comment: 0 6 * * 6 root /root/scripts/files.move.sh

Comment: probably it is your cron, the one who is wrong. I suppose your script is not actually executed. paste the output of you `crontab -l`. Then tell us, do you modify the cron file using `crontab -e` or you just modify the crontab file directly?

Comment: What are `/directory1/` and `/directory2/`? are they absolute paths? do they contain `~`?

Comment: @LuigiR.Viggiano
I edit it as a root user directly using vi.
The output of crontab -l says no crontab for root

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf
yes they actually contain ~

Comment: put their absolute paths! don't use the symbol `~`.

Comment: @misamisa, it means that your contab has not been *installed*. Try to edit your crontab using the command `crontab -e`; this will edit the file then load the cron configuration in the daemon, and your script will be invoked; and yes, using the `~` is not a good idea.

Comment: This is the weirdest question: it's tagged bash (and never implies bash, maybe only sh), about a script that supposedly doesn't work, but it turns out that it's a misuse of cron.

Comment: Thanks Luigi
I have edited the crontab -e and now crontab -l shows the jobs

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why your commands would fail, but the script can be made more defensive:

```
set -e; # bash specific, fail on error
/bin/mv /directory2 /directory3
/bin/mv /directory1 /directory2
/bin/rm -rf directory3
/bin/mkdir -p /directory1
```

Comment: Why not just remove directory2, rename directory1 to directory2, and then recreate directory1?

Comment: @bvukelic - because if renaming of directory1 to directory2 fails in the middle you have no good source to restore your backup from

Comment: As far as I know, renaming is an atomic operation, so won't "fail in the middle"

Comment: @glennjackman - even when dir1 and dir2 are on different file systems or multiple files dir1/* are copied to a single destination dir2?

Comment: obviously different filesystems are a different story. And you mentioned renaming a directory, not moving a bunch of files

Comment: @glennjackman - check the script code in the question - multiple files are moved to a single destination with one mv command